# Download a jpg image from the web saving it into a byte array on RAM

Tags: android

I’m trying to download a jpg image from the web saving it into a byte array in order to have the compressed image on the ram until I have to show it, but I’m getting a black picture.

What I’m doing is:

```
URL myFileUrl =null; 

myFileUrl= new URL(fileUrl);

HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.connect();
conn.setUseCaches(false);

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

byte[] ba = new byte[is.available()];
```

After that I’m keeping the array in the RAM until I have to use it.

To place it, I do:

```
Bitmap bitmapFromByteArray = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(ba,0,ba.length);

imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmapFromByteArray);

bitmapFromByteArray.recycle();
```

I solved the problem by doing

```
URL myFileUrl =null; 

myFileUrl= new URL(fileUrl);

HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myFileUrl.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.connect();

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

int size = bm.getWidth() * bm.getHeight();

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(size);
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

byte[] ba2 = out.toByteArray();
bm.recycle()
```

Buut by doing this I’m decoding the JPEG and then re-encoding the image multiple times lowering the quality of the picture and using the phone resources longer than necessary. Also, the bitmap I get after re-encoding is bigger than the original jpg image.

Is there any way to get the first method to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to simply copy the content of an `InputStream` into a byte array?

You can do this directly with a loop that calls `InputStream#read` into a byte array, or you can leave the implementation up to others by using [IOUtils.toByteArray](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) from Apache commons.

**Edit** - You don't need to deal with array initialization if you use the Apache commons method:

```
byte[] bytes = null;
try {
    bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(conn.getInputStream());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle the exception
}
```

`toByteArray` uses a `ByteArrayOutputStream` to avoid allocating an array up-front, but you wouldn't need to worry about this.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a noob question. the problem is that i have no idea if how to initialice the byte array. how long should it be? do by any chance you have an Apache commons (IOUtils) example?

Comment: Tank you. The app used to throw memoryOutOfBoundsException before (when I was saving theimages like Bitmaps), no I can save them as jpg (or kind of jpg) and mantain the quality.

Comment: I cannot find IOUtils. Can you say in which package is it included?

Niether I have io in org.apache.commons, that is why I couldn't get access to org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils .

Answer (score 0):

1. `byte[] ba = new byte[is.available()];` It's not that way you'll get the required bytes. The easiest  way to get that bytes is to use Apache commons ([IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html)). Your second approach decodes the bitmap directly from the HTTP input stream. It's also possible but it's better to download it first and than decode. Also you don't need to compress the bitmap after decoding. Just use it.
2. Bitmap should be recycled when it's not used. I don't think you can call `bitmapFromByteArray.recycle();` from that place you do it.

Comment: "Bitmap should be recycled when it's not used. I don't think you can call bitmapFromByteArray.recycle(); from that place you do it." you are right I have no Idea why I rote that in here. I don't have it like that on my app.